# How to load data from a DB only once in react?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios

I'm trying to figure out a way which I can load data from the database only once to a certain component.

```
useEffect(() => {
   axios.get("http://localhost:5000/members")
        .then(res => {
          setMembers(res.data)
        })
        catch(error => console.error(error.message))
})
```

Every time this component is loaded a request is made to the server for the "members". I need a way to make a request only one time, and which is when the component is being loaded for the very 1st time. Is there a way I can go about achieving this?

Answer (score 4):

Make the request *outside* your component's function. Promises only resolve once but the resolved value can be retrieved any number of times.

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

// Make the request here and keep a reference to the returned promise
const promise = axios.get("http://localhost:5000/members")
  .then(({ data }) => data);

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const [ members, setMembers ] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // set your state from the resolved promise
    promise.then(setMembers)
      .catch(err => console.error(err.toJSON()));
  }, []); // empty dependencies array means this only runs on mount

  return ( /* whatever */ );
};
```

[image: Edit unruffled-elbakyan-p7q50n]

You can see in the demo that the same component is loaded 3 times but the request is only made once.

Comment: Thanks, I have just tried this approach, however the request is still being made every time the component is loaded

Comment: @M_Magz what exactly do you mean by _"loaded"_? If you're reloading the page, of course everything gets loaded and evaluated again

Comment: I'm working on a dashboard page, in the "home" section of the dashboard I'm listing some sort of data, which I need to loaded only once and that when the dashboard page is first loaded. When ever I click on the link that directs me to the home section within my dashboard page, a request is being made to the server. I don't know if making sense

Comment: Are you using React Router or just regular browser navigation? You can see from the demo I added that the request is only ever made once.

Comment: I'm using react-router.
Yes I see the demo, and it really making the request once. 

Or maybe the problem is here:
```
// Show table when there is data in members
{ members.length > 1 &&  .... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Context to persist data throughout application or
you can use redux for storing data in centralized app state.

Answer (score -1):

You are doing one mistake here with useEffect as second argument not passed.

```
useEffect(() => {
   axios.get("http://localhost:5000/members")
        .then(res => {
          setMembers(res.data)
        })
        catch(error => console.error(error.message))
}, [])
```

Comment: This will still make the request every time the component is mounted

Comment: Yes but that's what needed.

Comment: _"make a request only one time, and which is when the component is being loaded for the very 1st time"_

Comment: My bad but isn't it will load the cached data instead of making request on every mount?

Comment: I think that's what OP wants

Answer (score -2):

You only need to add `[]` at the end of the useEffect hook in React. When a component loads data, it will not run this useEffect multiple times.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).